# how to find center of image using php imagemagick

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I want to use php5 and and the image processing library, imagemagick to locate the center of an image. I have imagemagick, and the php library installed, but i am just starting out, and stumbling through the examples. I haven't found anything that screams hey, this is how to do it!  To the same effect, I would like to know how to find the length, of the X & Y dimensions of an image, using imagemagick, because then, I would be able to calculate the center location.  Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your naswer:

```
$image = new Imagick("picture.jpg");
$width = $image->getImageWidth();
$height = $image->getImageHeight();

$center_width = $width / 2;
$center_height = $height / 2;
```

And now you have the coordinates of the center of the image! Tell me if you need further help.